# Reusing msg.value

Tags: transactions

Consider a simple payable deposit function.

```
function deposit() public payable returns (uint) {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

What is stopping somebody from calling this function multiple times in one transaction and reusing msg.value since it should stay the same inside 1 transaction? Maybe by making another contract that groups the calls together with delegatecall since that keeps the original msg.value?

I am guessing there is something inherently wrong with my thinking since this would make almost all contacts vulnerable but I couldn't find a good resource for this type of information. If somebody knows a good place to find out more about this type of information regarding how eth transactions work please link it. Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/@TrustChain/ethereum-msg-value-reuse-vulnerability-5afd0aa2bcef

Comment: Excluding external calls and transfer ether

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the msg.value will not remain constant throughout contract execution. EVM creates various transitional states during code execution and updates the msg.value field between these states.

You can find this kind of information on Ethereum yellow paper
(https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) See page 11, 8. Message Call

Answer (score 0):

> and reusing msg.value since it should stay the same inside 1 transaction?

Um, no? Where did you get that from? if make a smart contract that calls yours and i do :

```
function depositTo() public {
    yourContract.deposit{value: 2 ether}();
    yourContract.deposit{value: 1 ether}();
}
```

msg.value (as far as your contract is concerned) will be 2 ether on the first call and 1 on the 2nd.

Comment: But in this example it will be in 2 transactions? So it is not possible to call a payable function multiple times in a single transaction?

Comment: It's not 2 transactions, the user calls my depositFor() function, that's one single transaction.

Comment: Maybe you're mixing 2 concepts together, what you're referring to as a "transaction" is called a "message". More info here https://cryptocurrency.medium.com/messages-and-transactions-on-ethereum-3c4dadfe7986

Answer (score 0):

First of all the answer is msg.value is set on every contract call and not on the transaction level.

consider the following contract trying to do what you are saying:

```
contract depositer {
    function deposit(address weth) payable external {
        for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
            WETH(weth).deposit{value: msg.value}();
        }
    }
}
```

- The **first** iterration will use **all** msg.value
- The **second** iterration however will be **0** as the first one deposited all message value.

It seems you are thinking of reentrancy attack but that's not the case here, calling the same function in a loop is not an issue.

A reentrancy attack occurs when a function makes an external call to another untrusted contract. Then the untrusted contract makes a recursive call back to the original function in an attempt to drain funds. so it's basically not calling in a loop but calling in recursive from within the function being called.

Answer (score 0):

> What is stopping somebody from calling this function multiple times in one transaction and reusing msg.value since it should stay the same inside 1 transaction? Maybe by making another contract that groups the calls together with delegatecall since that keeps the original msg.value?

- Only happens when using `delegatecall`, msg.value persists when you’re using delegate-call.
- delegatecall only change status of calling contract, not contract of `function deposit()`
- Only cause issue, when you do address(this).delegatecall in base contract, and delegatecall to payable function deposit in your derived contract.

  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFSF3w73TwU
  - https://trustchain.medium.com/ethereum-msg-value-reuse-vulnerability-5afd0aa2bcef